# Excel VBA to add series data from a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, charts, range

I have a for loop to add a new data series to a chart. The data is in a different sheet than the chart. I keep getting a runtime error '1004' - Application-defined or object-defined error when I try to set the range where the data is located. This is my for loop (with some debugging code):

```
 For dataset = 2 To num_datasets
        next_series_startrow = end_1stdata_row + 3
        next_series_endrow = next_series_startrow + (end_1stdata_row - start_1stdata_row)
        test_range2 = Sheets(data_sheet).Range("CH32:CH55")
        Sheets(data_sheet).Activate
        data_range = Sheets(data_sheet).Range(Cells(next_series_startrow, start_1stdata_col), Cells(next_series_endrow, start_1stdata_col))
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
'        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(dataset).Values = Sheets(data_sheet).Range(Cells(next_series_startrow, start_1stdata_col), Cells(next_series_endrow, start_1stdata_col))
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(dataset).Values = data_range
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(dataset).Name = series_name(dataset)
        Next
```

test_range2 and data_range refer to the same range.

test_range2 works fine.

data_range only works if I first activate the sheet. If I remove `Sheets(data_sheet).Activate` then data_range throws a runtime error.

Ultimately, I would like to make

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(dataset).Values = Sheets(data_sheet).Range(Cells(next_series_startrow, start_1stdata_col), Cells(next_series_endrow, start_1stdata_col))
```

work so that I can do everything in one line.

Comment: `With Sheets(data_sheet):data_range = .Range(.Cells(next_series_startrow, start_1stdata_col), .Cells(next_series_endrow, start_1stdata_col)):End With`  *All* `Range` and `Cells` calls need an explicit worksheet reference if you want to avoid having your code break when the "correct" worksheet isn't active.

Comment: Also `SeriesCollection.NewSeries` returns the added series, so capture that in a variable and use that in place of the slightly clunky `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(dataset)`